# db_subst not working

Tags: debconf

I would like that the default value of my question is in the home directory of the current user.

file `templates`

```
Template: filesystem/root_path
Default: /home/${logname}/00_Files
Type: string
Description: The default directory to use when creating a new file.
```

file `config`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CONFIGFILE=/etc/filesystem.conf
set -e
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

db_subst filesystem/root_path logname "$(logname)"

# Load config file, if it exists.
if [ -e "$CONFIGFILE" ]; then
    . "$CONFIGFILE" || true

    # Store values from config file into
    # debconf db.
    db_set filesystem/root_path "$ROOT_PATH" || true
fi

# Ask questions.
db_input high filesystem/root_path || true
db_go || true
```

But the dialog produces `/home/${logname}/00_Files` without replacing the value.

Also how can I change the frontend for debconf?